# Is it possible to get email address as principalId while using Google OAuth with Spring security

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have an app that works with multiple Oauth2 sources, google being one of them. I want to be able to get the principalID or basically OAuth2AuthenticationToken.getName to be the email address rather than the long number that google provides. This is because I want to map this ID to some app specific user information and having to find out the long num for every user is a bit of a pain. Alternatively is there an easy way to get the identifier for every user?